# How to set pagination in android

Tags: android

I am Bringing records from Database and i need pagination as there are more number of Records..

[image]

Waiting for Response.Thanks in Advance

Comment: This [tutorial](http://blogs.technicise.com/android-listview-pagination/) can help you.

Comment: Thanks For the Response,But its not Working...I am a Beginner so Is there any other Simple way...? and  Is that possible to  pagination in xml file itself...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this also,
 *MainActivity.Java*

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {   

private ListView listview;
private TextView title;

private ArrayList<String> data;
ArrayAdapter<String> sd;


public int TOTAL_LIST_ITEMS = 1030;
public int NUM_ITEMS_PAGE   = 100;
private int noOfBtns;
private Button[] btns;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
title    = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);

Btnfooter();

data = new ArrayList<String>();

/**
 * The ArrayList data contains all the list items
 */
for(int i=0;i<TOTAL_LIST_ITEMS;i++)
{
    data.add("This is Item "+(i+1));
}

loadList(0);

CheckBtnBackGroud(0);

}

private void Btnfooter()
{
    int val = TOTAL_LIST_ITEMS%NUM_ITEMS_PAGE;
    val = val==0?0:1;
    noOfBtns=TOTAL_LIST_ITEMS/NUM_ITEMS_PAGE+val;

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.btnLay);

    btns    =new Button[noOfBtns];

    for(int i=0;i<noOfBtns;i++)
    {
        btns[i] =   new Button(this);
        btns[i].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        btns[i].setText(""+(i+1));

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ll.addView(btns[i], lp);

        final int j = i;
        btns[j].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                loadList(j);
                CheckBtnBackGroud(j);
            }
        });
    }

}
/**
 * Method for Checking Button Backgrounds
 */
private void CheckBtnBackGroud(int index)
{
    title.setText("Page "+(index+1)+" of "+noOfBtns);
    for(int i=0;i<noOfBtns;i++)
    {
        if(i==index)
        {
            btns[index].setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.box_green));
            btns[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        }
        else
        {
            btns[i].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
            btns[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
        }
    }

}

/**
 * Method for loading data in listview
 * @param number
 */
private void loadList(int number)
{
    ArrayList<String> sort = new ArrayList<String>();

    int start = number * NUM_ITEMS_PAGE;
    for(int i=start;i<(start)+NUM_ITEMS_PAGE;i++)
    {
        if(i<data.size())
        {
            sort.add(data.get(i));
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    sd = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            sort);
    listview.setAdapter(sd);
}
}
```

xml layout for the MainActivity.java

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.mycompany.databaseconnectoin.MainActivity">

   <ListView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/listView"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_below="@+id/horizontalScrollView">

   </ListView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:text="ddfdf"
        />
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView">
    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnLay"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/prev"
            android:text="Prev"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:text="Next"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Run this code and you will get your result. now make change according to your needs.
Also see this for only two button like 
[**Next & Previous**](https://paulononaka.wordpress.com/2011/03/19/how-to-implement-a-paging-feature-in-android/)

Comment: I am Getting Run Time Error

Comment: I am getting error in this line                                                         LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.btnLay);                         Error: btnLay cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: I still have query....When i min the NUM_ITEMS_PAGE=10 the total page is 103 and the scroll view is too long .Basically we need less scrolls.Is that possible to keep    [Prev] [1][2][3][Next] so that when i Click next the pagination goes to [Prev][4][5][6][Next].

Comment: I think now you can do like get a horizontal listview and two button for next and previous button, now whenever you click on next you can jump the horizontal listview adapter's item(on given gap) and notify the adapter.for previous button add the given gap and notify back to adapter.

Answer (score 0):

> You can create logic for that suppose you want to fetch 10 records from the database on single button click . please check below code

```
package com.example.editdemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private InputFilter filter;
Button prevButton, nextButton, bt1, bt2, bt3, bt4, bt5, bt6, bt7, bt8, bt9,
        bt10;

int cureentclcik;
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    prevButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            cureentclcik = cureentclcik - 1;

            int lastvalue = cureentclcik * 10;
            int statvalue = lastvalue - 10;

            for (int i = statvalue; i < lastvalue; i++) {

                // get value heree from your arraylist
                String value = data.get(i);
            }
        }
    });

    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            cureentclcik = cureentclcik + 1;
            int lastvalue = cureentclcik * 10;
            int statvalue = lastvalue - 10;

            for (int i = statvalue; i < lastvalue; i++) {

                // get value heree from your arraylist
                String value = data.get(i);
            }
        }
    });

    bt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            cureentclcik = Integer.parseInt(bt1.getText().toString());
            int lastvalue = cureentclcik * 10;
            int statvalue = lastvalue - 10;

            for (int i = statvalue; i < lastvalue; i++) {

                // get value heree from your arraylist
                String value = data.get(i);
            }
        }
    });
    bt2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            cureentclcik = Integer.parseInt(bt2.getText().toString());
            int lastvalue = cureentclcik * 10;
            int statvalue = lastvalue - 10;

            for (int i = statvalue; i < lastvalue; i++) {
                // get value heree from your arraylist
                String value = data.get(i);
            }
        }
    });

}

}
```

hope this will help you

Comment: I Still have doubt in your code if it is more than 10 in that case how to do it...  For eg: If i have 100 nos and in each page i am displaying 5 records whether i need to add btn11,btn12 ..? because my db gets updated twice a month and its really difficult to add like that...Is that possible to add number buttons in default so when i click next it automatically goes to btn11 to btn20..?

Comment: i update my answer.  you can add much buttons you want.

Comment: yes  preethi you can also create logic for that you just have to  set text in your buttons on previous button click or next button click

Comment: Yea I need the Code...It will be helpful If you post